# hard limit reached in flow dynamic choice dropdown

Tags: flow

I have a dynamic choice (dropdown list) in a visual flow that is pulling records (name, id) from a custom object and it has hit the size limit (200), but there are more records that need to be included.  Since 200 is a hard limit, what is the best approach to display the additional records in the dynamic choice?  If I add another dynamic choice, how do I make the field required for one or the other?  It seems like having two dropdown lists would be confusing for the user.

What is the best way to address this issue and get all records from the object to be displayed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is using a table instead of a dropdown list an option? You can have a small table with a filter option. You could also look into some plugins for dropdown lists that might let you get around the size limit (JQuery must have a bunch of these).

Comment: what about the possibility of adding a filter on the screen to only display certain records from the dynamic choice.  Something like: filter: name starts with "A".  The input could either  a list of the alphabet "A" thru "Z" or just an manual input and the condition would be name contains "some value" and it then filters the dynamic choice for just those values that meet the criteria.  Would that work?